# Unable to return Macro enabled Excel file from Azure Storage to Frontend via Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I cannot get a macro enabled file retrieved from Azure Storage Container via a Web Api to download in the front end (angular)

This is my API method, goes to Storage account, grabs the file and downloads:

```cs
[HttpGet("download/{fileSource}")]
public async Task<FileResult> DownloadFile([FromRoute] string fileSource)
{
    fileSource = "MyDetails.xlsm";
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_storageConnectionString);
    var blobCLient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobCLient.GetContainerReference("documents");
    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileSource);
          
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    try
    {
        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileSource);

               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        memoryStream.Dispose();
    }
          
}
```

This is my frontend call:

```
downloadFile(fileSource: string): Observable<Blob> {
let url = `${environment.APIURL}docs/download/${fileSource}`;
return this.http.get<Blob>(url, this.getDownloadFileHeaderOptions) 
.pipe(
  tap(response => {
    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileSource;
    a.click();
  })
);
}
```

fileSource = name of file

The `getDownloadFileHeaderOptions` is:

```
getDownloadFileHeaderOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    {               
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
};
```

The error I get is "Cannot access a closed Stream.", this is thrown after the API has returned File(memoryStream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you are disposing of the `MemoryStream` in a `finally` block. This means that as soon as your `DownloadFile` method completes and returns the `FileResult`, the `MemoryStream` is disposed of. However, the `FileResult` returned by the method doesn't actually read from the `MemoryStream` until after the method has returned, at which point the stream is already disposed.
To resolve the issue you can avoid disposing the `MemoryStream` within your API method.

You can try this below code:

```
[HttpGet("download/{fileSource}")]
public async Task<FileResult> DownloadFile([FromRoute] string fileSource)
{
    fileSource = "ServicePointDetails.xlsm";
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_storageConnectionString);
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("documents");
    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileSource);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    try
    {
        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileSource);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

"SyntaxError: Unexpected Token 'P' is not a valid JSON at JSON.parse" menas frontend is trying to parse the received response as JSON, but the content of the response is not in JSON format. In your code you are trying to download a file, the content of the response should be a stream of files, not JSON.

Front-end code:

```
downloadFile(fileSource: string): Observable {
let url = `${environment. APIURL}docs/download/${fileSource}`;
return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }) // Make sure the response type is 'blob'
.pipe(
tap(response => {
const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
const url = window. URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
a.download = fileSource;
document.body.appendChild(a); Make sure that the A element is added to the document
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a); clean
})
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared that error.  I now get SyntaxError: Unexpected Token 'P' is not a valid Json at Json.Parse

Comment: @CodeRatchet i have added the front end code as well

Comment: Currently get 

Generic type 'Observable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

What would the type be? Blob ?

Comment: I've added the Blob as the type, the calls work, but when the file is downloaded via the frontend the file type isn't recognised...

Comment: @CodeRatchet  you should specify the type parameter of 'Observable' as 'blob' and vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet mime type is correct